# Apache2 PHP out of memory (IP spoofing DDOS Attack?)

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, ddos

So I've got a BIG problem. For the last three days I've been getting "out of memory" errors. Never got a single one in the twenty years I've been doing IT before that.  It looks like someone is trying to hack one of my domains looking for a Wordpress install that doesn't exist. I can't block the IP address because they're just spoofing random addresses.

This is from the Apache2 error.log:

```
[Thu Aug 15 06:25:02.733995 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1381] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Aug 15 06:59:21.134619 2019] [:error] [pid 7779] [client 94.253.14.187:42493] script '/var/www/bibi/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Aug 15 07:00:00.195610 2019] [:error] [pid 7708] [client 103.87.207.188:43110] script '/var/www/bibi/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Aug 15 07:06:19.853931 2019] [:error] [pid 7708] [client 112.78.143.26:48640] script '/var/www/bibi/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Aug 15 10:45:59.613429 2019] [:error] [pid 8722] [client 45.86.245.113:45968] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 48234496) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/dhi/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/googlefonts.php on line 41
```

Here's what the access log shows:

```
[Wed Aug 14 08:51:09.646304 2019] [:error] [pid 21575] [client 35.156.206.70:60848] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 14680064) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/beauty/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1132, referer: http://www.example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1565772650.7416360378265380859375
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[Wed Aug 14 08:59:33.685188 2019] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 21569] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Wed Aug 14 08:59:45.065256 2019] [core:notice] [pid 21569] AH00051: child pid 22590 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Aug 14 08:59:45.080537 2019] [core:notice] [pid 21569] AH00051: child pid 22593 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Aug 14 08:59:45.080553 2019] [core:notice] [pid 21569] AH00051: child pid 22594 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Aug 14 08:59:45.080564 2019] [core:notice] [pid 21569] AH00051: child pid 22615 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Aug 14 08:59:45.080570 2019] [core:notice] [pid 21569] AH00051: child pid 22618 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
```

I tried deactivating the theme I've been using to see if that was the issue... I tried any number of things. I blocked the IP address that whoever is looking for xmlrpc.php in a directory that doesn't even have Wordpress installed was using... but now they're just spamming IP addresses.

Is there a way that I can block ANY IP address to that directory that is looking for that file? Is there a way that I can quit whatever is going on before it even gets to an out of memory error? What are my options?

Comment: don't think is DDOS, wouldn't be able to access the log files if that was the case (I believe anyway)

Comment: `48234496` = 46Meg which does not seem like a very large memory_limit for a WordPress site. Are you sure that you have not accidentally reduced the `memory_limit` in `php.ini`

Comment: @treyBake I was only able to access anything by stopping the server and starting again. Then I've got access for a few seconds... then it memory crashes again.

Comment: I would say, there is a process or PHP script, that is leaking memory.

Comment: @RiggsFolly That would be one hell of a psychopathic accident. Sleepwalk over to my computer... telnet into the server... edit the php.ini file... :)

Comment: Have the number of requests increased drastically in the past 3 days?

Comment: @user3783243 Absolutely not. None of my domains have even been announced to the public yet.

Comment: @Anuga Well what can I do about that? How do I find out which one and how do I fix it?

Comment: So I don't think it is a DDOS in that case. That is basically an influx of requests.

Comment: @user3783243 or maybe I just didn't understand what you meant. Maybe I could post more from the log files. Do you think I should expand the first section... or the second?

Comment: If you run `grep 'Aug 14' access.log | wc -l` and the same for the past 7 days what are the numbers looking like? If a bot is causing this and rotating IPs that should be an addition to your regular traffic so I would expect to see an increase from 3 days ago to today.

Comment: @user3783243 another interesting fact: Access.log is no longer logging anything. Not for the past couple of days. It's like the logs reached their max or something. The very last logs were the ones I posted. Error.log still seems to be working fine. So I'm not exactly sure how to fix access.log to get it running again.

Comment: Not sure about that. Sounds like this might be more a server question than coding. Might be more suited for serverfault.

Comment: @user3783243 maybe... maybe not. Just in case I updated Slider Revolution to the latest version because of this: [Thu Aug 15 10:45:59.613429 2019] [:error] [pid 8722] [client 45.86.245.113:45968] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 48234496) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/dhi/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/googlefonts.php on line 41

Comment: It was a VERY old version of Slider Revolution. Could've been some bug...

Comment: I would start by removing any plugins in Wordpress, its most likely a incompatible plugin that is cause the memory leak. Then add them back one by one, until the error reappears. (If it's caused by a plugin...)

Comment: @Anuga doesn't seem to be a plugin: [Sun Aug 18 19:48:14.670998 2019] [:error] [pid 1482] [client 103.80.236.106:50262] script '/var/www/bibi/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Aug 18 20:11:57.559451 2019] [:error] [pid 1481] [client 110.78.175.173:50725] script '/var/www/bibi/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Aug 18 20:14:09.279166 2019] [:error] [pid 1480] [client 103.209.89.66:46347] script '/var/www/bibi/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Aug 18 20:16:12.776276 2019] [:error] [pid 1483] [client 222.175.171.6:43192] script '/var/www/bibi/xmlrpc.php'

Comment: @Anuga That was today. And that particular server has nothing to do with wordpress at all.